# I have 4 colums with one being completely blank. How do I add info into the rows? When I add into the blank column, it becomes its own row.

Tags: sqlite

I have 4 columns Name, age, occupation and address. The first three were created and had info inserted into it. The fourth (address) was an ADDED column. (alter) How do I add into the fourth column to match the rows? Right now when I add, it becomes its OWN row. Thanks!!! (premie at SQL)

Comment: Can you show your schema/code for context? It's a bit hard to follow. Thanks! Not sure what you mean by "own row".

Comment: name        age         occupation     address   
----------  ----------  ----------         ----------
Jennings   22          chef                   
Jones        25          sous chef              
Smith        29          manager             
                                                       San Francisco

Comment: hmm... it doesn't show up as rows and columns. As you can see i'm a premie at this stuff. @will